# Keras 2.2.4 ERROR:AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'inbound_nodes'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, keras-2

I'm building a new channel wise operation for my network. 
A global average pooling result will multiply(element-wise) the first x(input) value. 
But, when i run the train.py file, it will occur errors which i couldn't understand. pls HELP!!！

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/githubRemote/train.py", line 49, in <module>
    model = init_model()
  File "E:/githubRemote/train.py", line 37, in init_model
    model = Model(inputs=im_n, outputs=resd)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 93, in __init__
    self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 231, in _init_graph_network
    self.inputs, self.outputs)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1366, in _map_graph_network
    tensor_index=tensor_index)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1353, in build_map
    node_index, tensor_index)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1353, in build_map
    node_index, tensor_index)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1353, in build_map
    node_index, tensor_index)
  [Previous line repeated 3 more times]
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1325, in build_map
    node = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'
```

My error code is the Multiply layer operation. 
When i comment the `net = Multiply()([x, excitation])`
It will work!
I think the keras model may consider that code line don't make a layer of Keras. So it's a NoneType -.-

My code:

```
def CAlayer(x, channel, reduction=16):
    # tensorflow implement
    # avg_pool = tflearn.global_avg_pool(inputx)
    # conv_1   = slim.conv2d(avg_pool, channel // reduction, 1)
    # conv_2   = slim.conv2d(conv_1, channel, 1, activation_fn=None)
    # excitation = tf.nn.sigmoid(conv_2)
    # keras implementation
    avg_pool   = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    avg_pool   = expand_dims(avg_pool, axis=1)
    avg_pool   = expand_dims(avg_pool, axis=1)
    conv_1     = Conv2D(channel//reduction, 1, activation=None, padding='same')(avg_pool)
    conv_1_ac  = Activation('relu')(conv_1)
    conv_2     = Conv2D(channel, 1, activation=None, padding='same')(conv_1_ac)
    excitation = Activation('sigmoid')(conv_2)
--> net = Multiply()([excitation, x])
    # print (net.shape)
    return net
```

Comment: `tf.keras.layers.Multiply` is a Layer class, just as other layers. In it's call function it expects tensors, not list

Answer (score 0):

In your code where you have used :

```
avg_pool   = expand_dims(avg_pool, axis=1)
```

this is causing the problem, as **expand_dims** is a function defined under keras.backend which
gives TensorFlow tensor as an output but all operations should be encapsulated in Keras layers.

You must use its equivalent Keras layer function. 
A rule of thumb: **All Keras layer functions start with a capital letter.**